# Erro ao converter mysql_list_tables para mysqli_

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma página para baixar um backup das informações do MySQL, porem está dando o seguinte erro desde que comecei a migrar de `mysql_` para `mysqli_`:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli as array in /home/.../public_html/biblioteca/backup.php on line 25

Antes eu havia acrescentado uma `,` dentro da chave `[, ]` mas deu erro também.

A linha de codigo do erro é:

```
$res = mysql_list_tables($mysqli [$dbname]) or die(mysqli_error("erro"));
```

Não achei como substituir a `mysql_list_tables`.

Comment: então, estou trocando todas as funções para mysqli e alterando conforme precisa, mas não consegui alterar a mysql_list_tables, não encontrei como fazer corretamente com ela. todas as funções da minha pagina ja estão em msyqli e estão funcionando bem, apenas esta q esta dando problemas.

Comment: obrigado pela dica. vou mudar o codigo e tentar novamente.

Comment: Editei sua pergunta para deixar o problema mais claro para outros visitantes, e para evitar negativação por alguém que não acompanhe os comentários, mas se não gostar da edição, você pode [reverter](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/119007/revisions) o que eu fiz. (mais tarde deleto este comentário aqui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode misturar funções das bibliotecas **mysql** e **mysqli**.

Acontece que a biblioteca **mysqli** não tem uma função diretamente equivalente à `mysql_list_tables`, mas é fácil obter a listagem usando uma *query* simples:

```
  $res = mysqli_query( $conexao, 'SHOW TABLES' );
  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res) ) $tabelas[] = $row[0];

  print_r( $tabelas );
```